# WebBrowser Control - Scrolling page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, facebook, webbrowser-control

Cant some one give me a better solution to programatically scroll the C# `WebBrowser` control window.
The method what is known to me, is not the best in practice. Now I looking for something else, a solution that allow to do that correctly.

The scrolling example used in my project, where I truing to load Facebook page with my photo, where I have a lot of this, take a lot of time >

```
private void AutoScroll_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
y++; 
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0,y);
if (y > (WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height))
{
y = 0;
AutoScroll.Enabled = false;
return;
}
}
```

I know on facebook page at `www.facebook.com/"username"/photos` - the loading_event is taken by a ajax/js scrips - and I think a solution to emulate this scripts will be a better for me.

If someone can explain me for the future, how to interaction with ajax/js scripts - and how to detect these events.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. You could use `window.scrollBy()` or `element.scrollIntoView()`, if that'd suit you better.

Comment: Nope, is not a good solution for me - to explain this - I find on codeproject a old article - that explain my problem - That's what I want to reproduce - the code on article don't work > http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=467494&av=668790 - look at the section with atag.GetAttribute("href").Contains("ajax/browser/list/allfriends")